# stable (?) model category of simplicial monoids

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, stable-homotopy, infinity-categories, stable-category

If $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of commutative unitary monoids, one can endow the category of simplicial objects in $\mathcal{C}$, $s\mathcal{C}$, with the structure of a cofibrantly generated model category, in which fibrations are those maps inducing fibrations of the underlying simplicial sets (on the other hand, weak equivalences are possibly not precisely those maps inducing weak equivalences on underlying simplicial sets, as commutative monoids are not always Kan fibrant).

Is the homotopy category $\text{Ho} \mathcal({C})$ triangulated?

Perhaps it is pre-triangulated, at best, but the suspension functor is not necessarily an equivalence?

Comment: You haven't given enough information to specify your model category- you can't give us *only* the fibrations, and from your parenthetical it sounds like you aren't just lifting the model structure from simplicial sets (otherwise equivalences would be detected below, independent of fibrancy.)

Comment: And I doubt that any natural choice of model structure that deserves to be called 'a homotopy theory of commutative monoids' would give you an additive homotopy category, let alone a triangulated one. And for sure you wouldn't be able to desuspend- which is already part of the definition of "pre-triangulated". I think what you'll get for any reasonable choice is a semi-additive homotopy category, and not really anything more.

Comment: (I mean, you could cheat and put a group completion in the definition of weak equivalence, and then you'd get simplicial abelian groups...and that'd give you the connective part of a triangulated category with a t-structure, which is probably the best you can get.)

Comment: $R$ a ring. In $R$-algebras and $R$-modules, effective epimorphisms are precisely the surjections on underlying sets, so one can put the model structures on rings given by declaring a map of rings $f$ to be "blah" iff for any projective $P$, $\text{Hom}(P, f)$ is "blah" as a map of simplicial sets. Then I'd show weak equivalences can be detected down below, as follows.

Comment: Any $R$-module is an abelian group. Any simplicial set is cofibrant. Any simplicial $R$-module, resp. $R$-algebra, $X$, has a cofibrant underlying simplicial set, because simplicial abelian groups are Kan fibrant. Then $X$ is fibrant-cofibrant. So map that induces weak equivalence on underlying simplicial sets, induces homotopy equivalence on underlying simplicial sets. Since homotopy equivalences are closed under arbitrary products, and since the forgetful functor to sets commutes with products, we're done because we can test "being a weak equivalence" on $P$ free. Converse true too and clear

Comment: When $R$ is only a semiring, one can put the same model structure on $R$-Mod and $R$-Alg, but the above argument breaks down because not true that the underlying simplicial set of a simplicial object in any of the two cat's, is a Kan complex.
But if the pf breaks down, doesn't mean weak equivalences can't be detected down below anyway, as I was assuming perhaps incorrectly. 
So: is it true that $f$ is a weak equivalence in $s\mathbf{N}$-Mod iff it is a weak equivalence of underlying simplicial sets?

I agree with your comments above. Thanks

Comment: If weak equivalences and fibrations are detected in sSet then this is the usual, well-studied, model structure on commutative monoids. It's not stable. I think pre-triangulated is fine, and works just like the discussion in Hovey's book for sSet.

Comment: Is there a reference somewhere where such model structure has been already eviscerated? I'd be glad not to have to work out several more things if already present in the literature

Comment: @DavidWhite it's worth pointing out that Hovey's use of "pre-triangulated" disagrees with the standard usage (i.e. as an additive category with a shift that satisfies all the axioms of a triangulated category except the octahedral axiom.) I haven't been able to find anywhere else that uses the term as Hovey does...

Comment: This model structure was really well-known. I think Quillen even knew about it. But, for the purpose of learning, a thorough discussion is in my JPAA paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6759. I'm not sure I "eviscerated" it. Have to think about that one. An earlier reference is Berger Moerdijk Axiomatic Homotopy Theory for Operads

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the references provided.